# BCrypt and javascript

Tags: javascript, шифрование

Использую для шифрования пароля при регистрации [jsBCrypt](https://github.com/PatrickHeneise/bcrypt/blob/master/bcrypt-angular.js).

Вот тут [код функции](http://pastebin.ru/V1NOiB1A).
Там комментариями описана проблема.
Как "вытянуть данные"? Т.е. шифрованный пароль доступен только в границах функции **bcrypt.hashpw**.

Заранее благодарен! )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция `hashpw()` работает асинхронно, значение получить вы сможете только после вызова функции `callback()`, пример:

```
var salt;
var gensalt = function(){
    var rounds = 5;
    salt = bcrypt.gensalt(rounds);
};
gensalt();

var crypt = function(call){
    bcrypt.hashpw(newUserDetails.password, salt, function (data){
        call(data);
    });
    console.log("End crypting password");
};

crypt(function(pass) { // call function after create password
    console.log(pass);
});
```

Comment: Это работает, да.  
Но значение шифрованного пароля опять же остается в границах функции
crypt().    
Мне же нужно потом значение шифрованного пароля newUserDetails.password передать методом POST на сервер:
  
     var request = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'rest/users/save',
        data: JSON.stringify(newUserDetails)
      };
      var responsePromise = $http(request);
      responsePromise.success(function(data) { });

Comment: @itslayo так передавайте!)

    crypt(function(pass) { // call function after create password

        newUserDetails.password = pass;

        var request = { method: 'POST', 
            url: 'rest/users/save', 
            data: JSON.stringify(newUserDetails) 
        }; 

        var responsePromise = $http(request);
        responsePromise.success(function(data) { });
    });

Comment: все)спасибо))справился))

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, может bcrypt.hashpw без колбека вызвать?

```
newUserDetails.password = bcrypt.hashpw(newUserDetails.password, salt);
```

Comment: так вообще ничего не работает. bcrypt.hashpw написана так, что результат пишет в функцию, которая идет параметром к ней